# How to extract difference in minutes between two datetimes vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform which automatically generates the current datetime and places it in a cell (end of a batch). The userform is then used again at a later time and it will repeat the step but place it in a different cell (Start of new batch).

I want to calculate the time difference between the two datetimes in minutes. The code I am using now is giving me strange negative answers for some reason when I subtract the early datetime from later datetime so there must be an error in it somewhere. (These dates may or may not be on the same day due to starting and ending batches after midnight).

When I simply try to subtract the two (without code) just using a cell formula I get an incorrect value of .05.

[image]

Does anyone know a way that I can have excel recognize these datetimes properly and subtract them so that minutes difference will be generated?

```
If opt1.Value = True And Range("U40") = "" Then
    Range("U40") = Format(txt1, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm")
    UserForm3.Hide
ElseIf opt1.Value = True And Range("U41") = "" Then
    Range("U41") = Format(txt1, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm")
    UserForm3.Hide
ElseIf opt1.Value = True And Range("U42") = "" Then
    Range("U42") = Format(txt1, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm")
    UserForm3.Hide
ElseIf opt2.Value = True And Range("W40") = "" Then
    Range("W40") = Format(txt1, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm")
    UserForm3.Hide
ElseIf opt2.Value = True And Range("W41") = "" Then
    Range("W41") = Format(txt1, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm")
    UserForm3.Hide
ElseIf opt2.Value = True And Range("W42") = "" Then
    Range("W42") = Format(txt1, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm")
    UserForm3.Hide
End If

If Range("U42") > "" And Range("W42") > "" Then
    Range("Y42") = Range("W42") - Range("U42")
ElseIf Range("U41") > "" And Range("W41") > "" Then
    Range("Y41") = Range("W41") - Range("U41")
ElseIf Range("U40") > "" And Range("W40") > "" Then
    Range("Y40") = Range("W40") - Range("U40")
End If
```

Comment: subtract the later time from the earlier time...

Comment: Sorry, just added some more info to the question. Subtracting does not work properly for some reason. Maybe because it is a custom date format?

Comment: datetime in excel are a count of positive numbers, when time is a fraction and date are integers. the 0.05 ia correct, as a fraction of 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time in Excel is stored as a fraction of a day. Subtracting gives you decimal days, you need to multiply to get to minutes:

`(Time B - Time A) * 60 Minutes in an hour * 24 Hours in a day`

[image]

`=(B1-A1)*60*24`

Answer (score 1):

Range("Y42") = DateDiff("n", Range("U42"), Range("W42"))

Answer (score 0):

Always subtract the smaller from the larger.

With the later date/time in **A1** and the earlier in **B1**, in **C1** enter:

```
=24*60*(A1-B1)
```

to get the difference in *minutes*:

[image]

Using VBA:

```
Sub datetime()
    Dim dt1 As Date, dt2 As Date
    dt1 = Range("A1").Value
    dt2 = Range("B1").Value
    MsgBox Int(24 * 60 * (dt1 - dt2))
End Sub
```

[image]